# Why am I getting an error when adding edges between two types of vertices?

Tags: import, etl, orientdb, graph-databases

I have two types of vertices: papers and entities.

Papers have a paper_id and entities have an entity_id. They're already imported properly from csv files using the ETL tool. Now I'm trying to add edges from papers to entities from a csv that is structured like this:

```
paper_id,entity_id
1,102030
1,203040
1,304050
2,304050
2,405060
```

I'm running the following file with the ETL tool:

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "/Users/Desktop/orientdb-3.0.6/bin/temp/files/small_con.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {} },
  "transformers": [
    {
    "command" : {
            "command" : "CREATE EDGE References from (SELECT from Paper where paper_id = ${input.paper_id}) to (select from Entity where entity_id = ${input.entity_id})",
            "output" : "edge"
        }
    }
   ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": 
"plocal:/Users/reagantifft/Desktop/Fall2018/SeniorProject/orientdb-3.0.6/databases/bv",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [

         {"name": "References", "extends": "E"}
       ]
    }
  }
 }
```

but my terminal output is the following... Note the error.

```
OrientDB etl v.3.0.6 - Veloce (build b63614ab180ff02b75d65054b2a77116c16c0a3c, branch 3.0.x) https://www.orientdb.com

2018-10-28 20:05:02:492 INFO  Default limit of open files (512) will be used. [ONative]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:592 INFO  8589934592 B/8192 MB/8 GB of physical memory were detected on machine [ONative]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:593 INFO  Detected memory limit for current process is 8589934592 B/8192 MB/8 GB [ONative]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:595 INFO  JVM can use maximum 1963MB of heap memory [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:596 INFO  Because OrientDB is running outside a container 2g of memory will be left unallocated according to the setting 'memory.leftToOS' not taking into account heap memory [OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:597 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=4,181MB (heap=1,963MB os=8,192MB) [orientechnologies]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:598 INFO  System is started under an effective user : `reagantifft` [OEngineLocalPaginated]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:640 INFO  BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR [OETLProcessor]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:642 INFO  [file] Reading from file /Users/reagantifft/Desktop/orientdb-3.0.6/bin/temp/files/small_con.csv with encoding UTF-8 [OETLFileSource]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:642 INFO  Started execution with 1 worker threads [OETLProcessor]
2018-10-28 20:05:02:994 INFO  Storage 'plocal:/Users/reagantifft/Desktop/Fall2018/SeniorProject/orientdb-3.0.6/databases//bv' is opened under OrientDB distribution : 3.0.6 - Veloce (build b63614ab180ff02b75d65054b2a77116c16c0a3c, branch 3.0.x) [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2018-10-28 20:05:03:646 INFO  + extracted 174 rows (0 rows/sec) - 174 rows -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 1004ms [0 warnings, 0 errors] [OETLProcessor]
2018-10-28 20:05:03:672 SEVER {db=bv} Error in Pipeline execution: [OETLPipeline]
2018-10-28 20:05:03:680 SEVER ETL process has problem:  [OETLProcessor]
2018-10-28 20:05:03:690 INFO  END ETL PROCESSOR [OETLProcessor]
2018-10-28 20:05:03:691 INFO  + extracted 368 rows (4,311 rows/sec) - 368 rows -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 1049ms [0 warnings, 1 errors] [OETLProcessor]
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? New to OrientDB and the ETL tool.

Comment: Did you try using the whole absolute path, something like C:/Users/Desktop/(...) for both 'path' and 'dbURL'?

Comment: I'm working it on a mac, so that is the absolute path on mine. Breaks if you add the MacintoshHD part. Plus the address worked for importing the paper and entity vertices and the output notes that it finds the file just fine.